# Estimating memory scope of erlang datastructure

Tags: c, arrays, memory, erlang

Being a former C programmer and current Erlang hacker one question has popped up.

*How do I estimate the memory scope of my erlang datastructures?*

Lets say I had an array of 1k integers in C, estimating the memory demand of this is easy, just the size of my array, times the size of an integer, 1k 32bit integers would take up 4kb or memory, and some constant amount of pointers and indexes.

In erlang however estimating the memory usage is somewhat more complicated, how much memory does an entry in erlangs array structure take up?, how do I estimate the size of a dynamically sized integer.

I have noticed that scanning over integers in array is fairly slow in erlang, scanning an array of about 1M integers takes almost a second in erlang, whereas a simple piece of c code will do it in arround 2 ms, this most likely is due to the amount of memory taken up by the datastructure.

I'm asking this, not because I'm a speed freak, but because estimating memory has, at least in my experience, been a good way of determining scalability of software.

---

My test code:

first the C code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

#include <queue>  
#include <iostream>

class DynamicArray{
protected:
  int* array;
  unsigned int size;
  unsigned int max_size;

public:
  DynamicArray() {
    array = new int[1];
    size = 0;
    max_size = 1;
  }

  ~DynamicArray() {
    delete[] array;
  }

  void insert(int value) {
    if (size == max_size) {
      int* old_array = array;
      array = new int[size * 2];
      memcpy ( array, old_array, sizeof(int)*size );

      for(int i = 0; i != size; i++)
        array[i] = old_array[i];
      max_size *= 2;
      delete[] old_array;
    }
    array[size] = value;
    size ++;
  }

  inline int read(unsigned idx) const {
    return array[idx];
  }

  void print_array() {
    for(int i = 0; i != size; i++)
      printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n ");

  }

  int size_of() const {
    return max_size * sizeof(int);
  }    

};


void test_array(int test) {
  printf(" %d ", test);
  clock_t t1,t2;
  t1=clock();
  DynamicArray arr;
  for(int i = 0; i != test; i++) {
    //arr.print_array();
    arr.insert(i);
  }
  int val = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i != test; i++)
    val += arr.read(i);
  printf(" size %g MB ", (arr.size_of()/(1024*1024.0)));  
  t2=clock();
  float diff ((float)t2-(float)t1);
  std::cout<<diff/1000<< " ms" ;
  printf(" %d \n", val == ((1 + test)*test)/2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int size = atoi(argv[1]);
  printf(" -- STARTING --\n");
  test_array(size);
  return 0;
}
```

and the erlang code:

```
-module(test).

-export([go/1]).

construct_list(Arr, Idx, Idx) ->
    Arr;
construct_list(Arr, Idx, Max) ->
    construct_list(array:set(Idx, Idx, Arr), Idx + 1, Max).

sum_list(_Arr, Idx, Idx, Sum) ->
    Sum;
sum_list(Arr, Idx, Max, Sum) ->
    sum_list(Arr, Idx + 1, Max, array:get(Idx, Arr) + Sum ).

go(Size) ->
    A0 = array:new(Size),
    A1 = construct_list(A0, 0, Size),
    sum_list(A1, 0, Size, 0).
```

Timing the c code:

```
bash-3.2$ g++ -O3 test.cc -o test
bash-3.2$ ./test 1000000
 -- STARTING --
 1000000  size 4 MB 5.511 ms 0
```

and the erlang code:

```
1> f(Time), {Time, _} =timer:tc(test, go, [1000000]), Time/1000.0.
2189.418
```

Comment: just small note: 1k 32bit integers will take 1024*4 = 4kb of memory

Comment: @IlyaBursov You are correct :)

Comment: Also, note that access time to `array` elements is not a constant. So it is better to traverse `list` of integers, it will require O(n) steps.

Comment: @danechkin the fact that the datastructure is event called an array is abit misleading :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, an Erlang variable is always just a single word (32 or 64 bits depending on your machine). 2 or more bits of the word are used as a type tag. The remainder can hold an "immediate" value, such as a "fixnum" integer, an atom, an empty list ([]), or a Pid; or it can hold a pointer to data stored on the heap (tuple, list, "bignum" integer, float, etc.). A tuple has a header word specifying its type and length, followed by one word per element. A list cell on the uses only 2 words (its pointer already encodes the type): the head and tail elements.

For example: if A={foo,1,[]}, then A is a word pointing to a word on the heap saying "I'm a 3-tuple" followed by 3 words containing the atom foo, the fixnum 1, and the empty list, respectively. If A=[1,2], then A is a word saying "I'm a list cell pointer" pointing to the head word (containing the fixnum 1) of the first cell; and the following tail word of the cell is yet another list cell pointer, pointing to a head word containing the 2 and followed by a tail word containing the empty list. A float is represented by a header word and 8 bytes of double precision floating-point data. A bignum or a binary is a header word plus as many words as needed to hold the data. And so on. See e.g. http://stenmans.org/happi_blog/?p=176 for some more info.

To estimate size, you need to know how your data is structured in terms of tuples and lists, and you need to know the size of your integers (if too large, they will use a bignum instead of a fixnum; the limit is 28 bits incl. sign on a 32-bit machine, and 60 bits on a 64-bit machine).

Edit: https://github.com/happi/theBeamBook is a newer good resource on the internals of the BEAM Erlang virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
1> erts_debug:size([1,2]).
4
```

with it you can at least figure out how big a term is. The size returned is in words.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang has integers as "arrays", so you cannot really estimate it in the same way as c, you can only predict how long your integers will be and calculate average amount of bytes needed to store them

check: http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html and you can use `erlang:memory()` function to determine actual amount

Comment: erlang:memory will only answer the question on a running application, I would like to say things like storing 10mio entries that will take 40mb of memory. Not just lets start with 100 and see if the memory likes it :)

Comment: @MartinKristiansen so, read my first paragraph, if you know the ranges of of these 10m numbers - you can estimate how many bytes will take each of them

Comment: This is what I dont understand, small integers would take up 60(64) bits, making them 16 byte integers, but scanning over them is a factor of five hundred slower than the c program..

Comment: even for small integer erlang has to store: variable type, array length, at least byte for each digit in number, this can explain both: memory usage and performance problems

Comment: I think you are partly right - the four bits missing from the 60bit integer are most likely used to denote the variable type, since there are only 14 variable types, I would guess that the length of the integer is contained in the fact that its  a small integer type. I would guess the slow execution time to be due to the about of strange checks that erlang needs to do, every add operation has to determine what type the result will have, and since the types are strange, and variable length an array cannot be layedout in sequence in memory.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen yep, thats what I meant, you can also suppose each integer as struct, and array of integers as some kind of dynamically allocated linked list